# Rails: query children and grandchildren, run method on child, SQL SUM on grandchildren -- resulting in array?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parent, children

**Models:**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :inventories
  has_many :stocks, through: :inventories
end

class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :stocks
end

class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :inventory
end
```

**Goal:**

Achieve an efficient ActiveRecord query that builds an array like this:

```
[
   { name: "Supplies", count: 10.00, total_value: 40.00 },
   { name: "Materials", count: 25.00, total_value: 30.00 }
]
```

**name** -> just a regular attribute in Inventory model

**count** -> a SQL SUM on the :count column in stocks table

**total_value** -> from a method in the Inventory model that does some math

This could be a total fantasy but I have a large dataset so am trying to make this hyper efficient. Any ideas?

---

**Edit to answer question:**

total_value is a method on Inventory that then calls a sum of a method on Stock:

```
def total_value
  stocks.map do |stock|
    stock.total_cost
  end.sum
end
```

total_cost is a method on Stock:

```
def total_cost
  cost_per_unit * count
end
```

Comment: Could you give the code for the method that computes `total_value`?

Comment: Sure! just edited my post with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: `query = Inventory.group(:id, :name).select(:id, :name).left_joins(:stocks).select("SUM(stocks.count) AS count").select("SUM(stocks.cost_per_unit * stocks.count) AS total_value")`

`query.as_json` gives what you're looking for.

You can also access the data via `find_each`: `query.find_each { |record| puts "record #{record.name} has a total value of #{record.total_value}" }`

**If you want to avoid duplicating the logic** of `total_value` in SQL, you **have** to load stocks records, which considerably slows down the computation if there are many:

Upgrade the model

```
class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
  def stocks_count
    stocks.sum(&:count)
  end

  def total_value
    stocks.sum(&:total_cost)
  end
end
```

And the query

```
Inventory.preload(:stocks).map do |inventory|
  {
    name: inventory.name, 
    count: inventory.stocks_count, 
    total_value: inventory.total_value
  }
end
```

**If you want to optimize your query to the max**, you may consider caching 2 columns `total_value` and `stocks_count` on the `inventories` table. You would update them everytime one of its stocks changes (creation, deletion, update). It's harder to maintain but that's the fastest option.

Comment: Can you think of a way to leave "total_value" as a method call instead of building it into the query? I use this method throughout my app and wanted to have one "source of truth" for it.

Comment: Actually, that's probably what you meant by recommending find_each? I'll try that out some more.

Comment: Edited, you've got all the options now ;)

Comment: Great point about caching, I hadn't considered that either. I really appreciate the help here, thank you!